# Install magento into an existing wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have a **wordpress** site online and I'd like to integrate Magento into my existing site.


Okay so I want to

- Download the Magento files
- Setup my Apache configuration, for this I already have my site configuration, so I was thinking about putting magento in this url mysite.com/my-store/ ... but for this on apache should I use "location" directive?
- What else do I need to consider?

Comment: Let's do the following 1). Download and install magento in **my-store** folder on the same server where you have installed Wordpress. 2). Either you can use same or different **DB** 3). Once you have installed magento then install **fishpig** extension ....................:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about is install Magento in new folder and create new database as Magento requires a lot of resources and you don't want get it mixed.

It all depends what exactly is that you planning to achieve. Either to use your domain name as a main ecommerce and setup the Wordpress as a directory

```
domain-name.com/blog
```

if it's a blog or something, or you can setup an alias that points to the folder and have something like this:

```
store.domain-name.com
```

Another way to do it if you would like to have everything integrated is to use [FishPig Extension](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) and then simply update all the WordPress plugins and point it to your existing database.

Answer (score 0):

these are two seperate programs so best would be to get a plugin for wordpress and integrate magento inside there are a few plugins like this out there http://www.mwi-plugin.com/